# How to enable authentication Jenkins?

Tags: java, heroku, jenkins

I installed the Jenkins on Heroku,
but I do not know how to configure authentication and
how should I do to create an admin user from my account.

Note: When you access the official site Jenkins a message appears saying that is under maintenance: "Our website is currently down for maintenance ..."

Would someone give me a help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know Heroku but if you would host jenkins on your own you can achieve it this way:

1. go to "manage jenkins" -> global security
2. activate security using jenkins own user-database
3. DO NOT activate matrix-based security yet.
4. Save!
5. go to "manage jenkins" -> "manage users"
6. create a user. use only lowercase letters for the username otherwise you will get problems on restart of jenkins.
7. now go back to "manage jenkins" -> global security
8. activate matrix-based security
9. enter the name of your new user and give him all permissions using the button at the end of the row.
10. Save
11. now you should be able to login.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ChrisKo, now it's all working!